# How to set component value in a generic react hook method that handles multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am going through some tutorials to understand react hooks. I have eventHandler method that handle changeEvent for all input fields in a form. I want to set the value of the inputField from where the changeEvent was raised. I cannot hardcode the input field id in the hook, as it is a generic method handling multiple fields in the form. See the comment in the setForm call, that explains the issue

```
// Defining the useState Hook
const [form, setForm] = useState({
    firstName: defaultFirstNameText,
    lastName: defaultLastNameText,
    emailAddress: defaultEmailText
});

// EventHandler method
function handleFormChange(e, defaultTextValue) {

    const componentId=e.target.id;

    if(e.target.value == ""){
        e.target.value=defaultTextValue
    }
    setForm({
        ...form,
        componentId: e.target.value **// This has a syntax error, understandably - curlybraces doesnt help either: I can do "firstName: e.target.value" but i cannot hardcode the component id, as this is a generic event handler. componentId could be firstName or lastName or emailAddress. hardcoding will work, which i dont want -> i.e. firstName: e.targetValue
    });**
}

    // Component
    <label>
        First name:
        <input id="firstName"
            onChange={(event) => handleFormChange(event, defaultFirstNameText)}  
            ......
```

Thanks
Tim

I tried referring to componentId variable directly, with curlybrace etc. it didnt help.
Hardcoding works, but i want this to be generic. I want to refer to e.target.id and not hardcoded componentId. Tried searching on stackoverflow, react community. couldnt find solutions.
setForm({
...form,
firstName: e.target.value